# how to get specific set of records in sql server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2

Say I have 50 records in my table,(unique id is auto increment from 1 to 50) how do I retrieve records 10 to 30 using a sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from yourTable
where yourIdColumn between 10 and 30
```

Replace `yourTable` with your table's name, and `yourIdColumn` with the name of your unique id field.

Comment: I just edited my question, a mistake while typing, wanted records 10 to 30

Comment: @akriy no problem, I've just edited my post to include the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columnlist
FROM yourTable
WHERE IDColumn BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```